# service from Angular 4 and CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, json, angular, codeigniter

I have a problem about service in Angular2/4.
I keep getting

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0.

This is my backend using CI.
This is my controller `book.php`:

```
//get book from database
function list_book_get()
{
    //call method get_list_book() in model m_book
    $dataBook = $this->m_book->get_list_Book();

    //if dataBook exist
    if($dataBook != null) { 
        $output['status'] = true;
        $output['data'] = $dataBook;
    } else {    // if dataBook not exist
        $output['status'] = false;
        $output['message'] = "empty";
    }

    //send response
    $this->response(json_encode($output));
}
```

The model in CI:

```
function get_list_book() {  
        return $this->db->get('book')->result();
    }
```

And this is my service in Angular 4:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' ;

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

    books=[];
    getBooks(){
      return this.http.get("http://localhost/restserver/book/list_book.php")
      .map(res => res.json());
    } 


}
```

That is my json from CI:

```
'{"status":true,"data":
[{"id":"1","title":"SAINS","author":"ERLANGGA","isbn":"089928778"},
{"id":"2","title":"Geography","author":"ERLANGGA","isbn":"089182372"},
{"id":"3","title":"Math","author":"Srilangka","isbn":"091283181"},
{"id":"4","title":"test","author":"test","isbn":"1283798127"},
{"id":"5","title":"AAAA","author":"BBB","isbn":"91092301290"},
{"id":"6","title":"BBB","author":"CCC","isbn":"01920192"}]}'
```

I assume that quotation mark (') in my json that make my apps error.
How to remove that quotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to send json reponse from CI `Controller` is :

```
function list_book_get()
{
    ...
    return $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($output));
}
```

> You are getting json in single quotes bcoz (means as string) , you
>   haven't defined the content type.

Comment: hey can i ask you something, now my frontend (angular) give this error "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." you know why ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951513/angular-4-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-ob thats the link sir